# Can't assign a value (user id) to a ForeignKey field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting the following error:
`Cannot assign "<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey>": "Worry.user" must be a "User" instance.`

I trying to assign the id of the current user to an object I have just created.

This is part of my models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from django.forms import ModelForm  
from django.db import models  

    class UserForm (ModelForm) :  
        class Meta:  
            model = User        
    class Worry(models.Model) :    
        user = models.ForeignKey(User) #Many worries to 1 user relation
```

This is part of my views.py:

```
from django.db import models  
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect, get_object_or_404  
from django.template import RequestContext  
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from holaProy.models import UserForm, Worry, WorryForm, Statistics, StatisticsForm  
def worry_add (request):  
    form = WorryForm (request.POST or None)  
    if form.is_valid():      
        wform.user = models.ForeignKey('User')  #HERE IS THE PROBLEM I THINK
        wform.save()  
        return redirect (index)  
    return render_to_response ('holaProy/worry_add.html', {'worry_form': form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))</code>
```

How should I do it in order to succesfully assign the current user id to the "user" field for the actual worry instance?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is, indeed, on that line:

```
wform.user = models.ForeignKey('User')
```

`wform.user` should be set to a `User` instance. Something like this:

```
user = request.user    # Retrieve proper user according to your needs
wform.user = user
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def worry_add(request):
    form = WorryForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        worry = form.save(commit=False)
        worry.user = #assign this to an instance of a User object
        worry.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the line where you are having your problem.

Basically, you are searching for a string.  You need to get the actual database object before.
Try this:

```
User = User.objects.get(pk='User')
wform.user = models.ForeignKey('User')  #Now User refers to the database object, not a string
```